# How to add extra metadata when writing to parquet files using spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

Looks like spark by default write "org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.row.metadata" to parquet file footer. However, what if I want to write some random metadata(such as version=123) to a parquet file produced by spark?

This does NOT work:

```
df.write().option("version","123").parquet("somefile.parquet");
```

And I'm using spark version 1.6.2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32628845/is-there-a-way-to-add-extra-metadata-for-spark-dataframes
this provides some samples of how you <i>could</i> do it, but there isn't a built-in way (to my knowledge:( )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column level metadata, yes see my comment.

Table level comments/user metadata: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10803

Sadly, not yet

Comment: what about Spark 2?