# Spark - How to use QuantileDiscretizer with RandomForestClassifier

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

Is it possible to use **QuantileDiscretizer**, `keep`ing `NaN` values, with a **RandomForestClassifier**?

I have been getting an error like this:

```
18/03/23 17:38:15 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 133.0 (TID 381)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DecisionTree given invalid data: Feature 1 is categorical with values in {0,...,1, but a data point gives it value 2.0.
  Bad data point: (1.0,[1.0,2.0])
```

### Example

The idea here is to create a numeric column and discretize it using quantiles, keeping invalid numbers (`NaN`) in a special bucket.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{StringIndexer, VectorAssembler,
  QuantileDiscretizer}
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.{RandomForestClassifier}

val tseq = Seq((0, "a", 1.0), (1, "b", 0.0), (2, "c", 2.0),
               (3, "a", 1.0), (4, "a", 3.0), (5, "c", Double.NaN))
val tdf = SparkInit.ss.createDataFrame(tseq).toDF("id", "category", "class")
val indexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("category")
  .setOutputCol("categoryIndex")
val discr = new QuantileDiscretizer()
  .setInputCol("class")
  .setOutputCol("quant")
  .setNumBuckets(2)
  .setHandleInvalid("keep")
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("categoryIndex", "quant"))
  .setOutputCol("features")
val rf = new RandomForestClassifier()
  .setLabelCol("categoryIndex")
  .setFeaturesCol("features")
  .setNumTrees(3)
new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(indexer, discr, assembler, rf))
  .fit(tdf)
  .transform(tdf)
  .show()
```

Without trying to fit the Random Forest, I was getting a DataFrame like this:

```
+---+--------+-----+-------------+-----+---------+
| id|category|class|categoryIndex|quant| features|
+---+--------+-----+-------------+-----+---------+
|  0|       a|  1.0|          0.0|  1.0|[0.0,1.0]|
|  1|       b|  0.0|          2.0|  0.0|[2.0,0.0]|
|  2|       c|  2.0|          1.0|  1.0|[1.0,1.0]|
|  3|       a|  1.0|          0.0|  1.0|[0.0,1.0]|
|  4|       a|  3.0|          0.0|  1.0|[0.0,1.0]|
|  5|       c|  NaN|          1.0|  2.0|[1.0,2.0]|
+---+--------+-----+-------------+-----+---------+
```

If I try to fit the model, I get the error:

```
18/03/23 17:54:12 WARN DecisionTreeMetadata: DecisionTree reducing maxBins from 32 to 6 (= number of training instances)
18/03/23 17:54:12 WARN BlockManager: Putting block rdd_490_3 failed due to an exception
18/03/23 17:54:12 WARN BlockManager: Block rdd_490_3 could not be removed as it was not found on disk or in memory
18/03/23 17:54:12 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 143.0 (TID 414)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DecisionTree given invalid data: Feature 1 is categorical with values in {0,...,1, but a data point gives it value 2.0.
  Bad data point: (1.0,[1.0,2.0])
    at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.TreePoint$.findBin(TreePoint.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.TreePoint$.org$apache$spark$ml$tree$impl$TreePoint$$labeledPointToTreePoint(TreePoint.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.TreePoint$$anonfun$convertToTreeRDD$2.apply(TreePoint.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.TreePoint$$anonfun$convertToTreeRDD$2.apply(TreePoint.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:216)
```

Does **QuantileDiscretizer** inserts some kind of metadata about the special extra bucket? It's weird that I was able to build a model using columns with the same values before, but without forcing any discretization.

### Update

Yes, columns does have attached metadata and it looks like this:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata = {"ml_attr":
   {"ord":true,
    "vals":["-Infinity, 5.0","5.0, 10.0","10.0, Infinity"],
    "type":"nominal"}
}
```

The question now might be: how to set correctly the metadata to include values like `Double.NaN`?

Comment: have you fixed this problem yet? I'm running into the same problem here and this is the only relavant post after I google it.

Comment: @SpiritZhang, I found a workaround that was OK for my model. I'm going to describe it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I used was simply to remove the associated metadata from the discretized columns, letting the decision tree implementation to decide what to do with the data. I think the column would actually become a numerical column (`[0, 1, 2, 2, 1]`, for example), but, if too many categories are created, the column could be discretized again (look for the parameter `maxBins`).

In my case, the simplest way to remove the metadata was to `fill` the DataFrame after applying **QuantileDiscretizer**:

```
// Nothing is actually filled in my case, since there was no missing
// values before this operation.
df.na.fill(Double.NaN, Array("quant"))
```

I'm almost sure you could also manually remove the metadata accessing the column object directly.

### Update

We can change a column's metadata by creating an alias ([reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@as(alias:String,metadata:org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)):

```
val metadata: Metadata = ...
df.select($"colA".as("colB", metadata))
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40094559/747872) describes a way to get the column's metadata by getting the respective `StructField` of a DataFrame's schema.

Comment: I tried this method on my pyspark code but didn't work. Could you please explain why fill a dataframe will remove its metadata?

Comment: @SpiritZhang, did you add all your discretized columns in the `Array()` above? I didn't check the exact code line in Spark's source code, but I manually checked the metadata of my column after the operation. I believe that `fill` automatically removes any metadata associated to the respective columns.