# Spark Add Meta Data to Parquet / ORC Files

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

On a daily basis, I need to summarise the activities of customers for various use cases. In order to maintain / not overwrite I make sure that every time I am writing to parquet (partitioned by date) I delete any previous data that I have stored for this date. However, for some use cases, I have issues doing the above.

1. I want to store activity every hour for a customer
2. I want to store activity every minute for every customer

I want to store these both in the same partition.

Example Code

```
def delete_and_write(file_location):
      #1. if file_location exists delete
      #2. Write below
      df.repartition(1)
        .write.partitionBy("date")
        .save(file_location, format=file_format, mode='append', header='true')
```

I want to do something like the following

```
def delete_and_write():
    #1. If file with specific meta data info exists delete
    #2. Write data with meta data such 1 hour window or so
```

So basically instead of deleting the file if it resides in a location, I want to only delete parts of the file with specific information/metadata. Is this possible? For example, if I am writing customer activity within 1 hour and this info already exists I want to delete this info only and not everything in the file location.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32628845/is-there-a-way-to-add-extra-metadata-for-spark-dataframes has some nice examples of adding metadata to parquet files, is that what you're looking for?